# Expand row in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, rowexpansion

Requirement is to provide through Vaadin Table , like row expand. On Click of the more detail which available in Every Column should add the component and show below the row.

I have same like requirement as shown in grid3.js through Sencha, but need a table.

Comment: can you use a TreeTable http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-presentation/tree-table http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples/book/1_221/#component.treetable.basic ?  or write your own behaviour http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples/book/1_221/#component.table.components.interactingcomponents